# React Router Nest Routes Without JSX

Tags: react-router, code-splitting

I'm using webpack 2 / code splitting so I have my routes like so

```
import App from './components/App';
import Portal from './components/portal/Portal';

const componentRoutes = {
  component: App,
  path: '/',
  indexRoute: { component: Portal },
  childRoutes: [
    {
      path: 'login',
      getComponent(location, cb) {
        System.import('./components/login/Login')
          .then(module => cb(null, module.default));
      }
    },
    {
      path: 'home/:id',
      getComponent(location, cb) {
        System.import('./components/homepage/HomeContainer')
          .then(module => cb(null, module.default));
      }
    },
    {
      path: 'home/:id/assessments',
      getComponent(location, cb) {
        System.import('./components/assessment/AssessmentContainer')
          .then(module => cb(null, module.default));
      } 
    },
    {
      path: 'home/:id/manage_classes',
      getComponent(location, cb) {
        System.import('./components/manageClasses/manageClassesContainer')
          .then(module => cb(null, module.default));
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

But I want to nest my routes like this:

```
import Login from './components/login/Login';
import HomeContainer from  './components/homepage/HomeContainer';
import Unit from './components/homepage/Units'
import AssessmentContainer from './components/assessment/AssessmentContainer';
import ManageClassesContainer from './components/manageClasses/manageClassesContainer';

const componentRoutes = (
  <Route path='/' component={App}>
    <Route path='login' component={Login} />

    <Route path='home/:id' component={HomeContainer}>
      <IndexRoute component={Unit} />
      <Route path='home/:id/assessments' component={AssessmentContainer} />
      <Route path='home/:id/manage_classes' component={ManageClassesContainer} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
);
```

How do you have nested routes inside the nested routes array? When I navigate to `home/:id` I don't want to lose all the JSX `HomeContainer` provides and I just want to call use `{props.children}` to render the child routes. When you use code splitting you can't use JSX so that's why I'm trying to refactor.

Comment: whats not working for you?

Comment: @Sag1v the first example isn't set up to handle nested nested routes. Everything is under '/'. If you compare the non-jsx vs jsx version you can see that they are different. I want non-jsx to do exactly like the jsx does

Comment: ok i missunderstood, i thought it was the other way around. and why exactly you don't want the normal jsx?

Comment: @Sag1v I explained in the post - but because I'm using code splitting you can't use jsx

Comment: do you use `CommonsChunkPlugin`?

Comment: @Sag1v yeah I do

Comment: well, i do too and i use jsx for my routes. don't see a problem with that. where did you read that you can't or what problems do you get when using jsx?

Comment: I tried to add those routes but it didn't work. However, I found the answer here:  https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/DynamicRouting.md